# Simple derivative of summation

Tags: calculus

I am a bit confused as to how the derivative of a summation works. I am trying to calculate the following:

$d/d{x_i} \sum_{i} x_i + cx_i$

Would the answer just be 1 + c then?

Any resources where I can learn more about this?
Thanks!

Comment: What is $\nabla_{x_i}$ supposed to mean??

Comment: Well what is $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1} (x_1+x_2+x_3)$?

Answer (score 0):

If we're more careful, we write the problem as$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\sum_jx_j+cx_i\right)=\sum_j\delta_{ij}+c=1+c,$$with $\delta_{ij}$ the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).